# How with Java to convert an *abracadabra* back to string like it does JavaScript decodeURIComponent(escape(x))?

Tags: java, decode, encode

I have a string (hexadecimal per-byte presentation):

> `\xC3\x90\xC2\x9E\xC3\x91\xC2\x88\xC3\x90\xC2\xB8\xC3\x90\xC2\xB1\xC3\x90\xC2\xBA\xC3\x90\xC2\xB0\x20\xC3\x90\xC2\xB2\xC3\x90\xC2\xB0\xC3\x90\xC2\xBB\xC3\x90\xC2\xB8\xC3\x90\xC2\xB4\xC3\x90\xC2\xB0\xC3\x91\xC2\x86\xC3\x90\xC2\xB8\xC3\x90\xC2\xB8\x20\xC3\x90\xC2\xB0\xC3\x91\xC2\x82\xC3\x91\xC2\x80\xC3\x90\xC2\xB8\xC3\x90\xC2\xB1\xC3\x91\xC2\x83\xC3\x91\xC2\x82\xC3\x90\xC2\xBE\xC3\x90\xC2\xB2\x20\xC3\x90\xC2\xB4\xC3\x90\xC2\xBE\xC3\x90\xC2\xBA\xC3\x91\xC2\x83\xC3\x90\xC2\xBC\xC3\x90\xC2\xB5\xC3\x90\xC2\xBD\xC3\x91\xC2\x82\xC3\x90\xC2\xB0` [1]

It looks just like this:

> `ÐÑÐ¸Ð±ÐºÐ° Ð²Ð°Ð»Ð¸Ð´Ð°ÑÐ¸Ð¸ Ð°ÑÑÐ¸Ð±ÑÑÐ¾Ð² Ð´Ð¾ÐºÑÐ¼ÐµÐ½ÑÐ°` [2]

You can use http://0xcc.net/jsescape/ to see it. Just paste the hexadecimal sequence into the `\xXX` field there, and the string will be displayed in the `Plain text` field.

This string [2] should be recovered after (unknown and obviously wrong) encoding.

If (on the same web site http://0xcc.net/jsescape/) you will copy the *abracadabra* [2] from `Plain text` and paste it into `Quoted-printable`, you will see the decoded one in the `Plain text` field:

> `Ошибка валидации атрибутов документа` [3]

The same could be done with JavaScript by `decodeURIComponent(escape(x))` where `x` contains the *abracadabra* string [2].

So my question is: how can I recover the *original* string [3] from the *abracadabra* [2] using Java ?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String contains chars, where a char is a two-byte UTF-16 value. Bytes, binary data, holding text must be associated with an encoding, as **String holds Unicode**. Java introduced this clear distinction between `byte` and `char`.

With regex replace one could manually convert as:

```
    byte[] arr = {(byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0x9E, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x91, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0x88, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xB8, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xB1, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xBA, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xB0, (byte) 0x20, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xB2, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xB0, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xBB, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xB8, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xB4, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xB0, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x91, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xB8, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xB8, (byte) 0x20, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xB0, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x91, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x91, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xB8, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xB1, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x91, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0x83, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x91, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xBE, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xB2, (byte) 0x20, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xB4, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xBE, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xBA, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x91, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0x83, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xBC, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xB5, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xBD, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x91, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xB0};
    String s = new String(arr, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Translating an ASCII text with backslash, x, and two hex digits must go as:

```
    String t = "\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\x9E\\xC3\\x91\\xC2\\x88\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xB8\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xB1\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xBA\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xB0\\x20\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xB2\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xB0\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xBB\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xB8\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xB4\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xB0\\xC3\\x91\\xC2\\x86\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xB8\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xB8\\x20\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xB0\\xC3\\x91\\xC2\\x82\\xC3\\x91\\xC2\\x80\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xB8\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xB1\\xC3\\x91\\xC2\\x83\\xC3\\x91\\xC2\\x82\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xBE\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xB2\\x20\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xB4\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xBE\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xBA\\xC3\\x91\\xC2\\x83\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xBC\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xB5\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xBD\\xC3\\x91\\xC2\\x82\\xC3\\x90\\xC2\\xB0";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\\\x(..)").matcher(t);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while (m.find()) {
        baos.write(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16));
    }
    s = baos.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

In both cases the original bytes where decoded as UTF-8. However the String is still
"encoded." Actually it was twice UTF-8 encoded, an error, not guaranteeing that unencoding/decoding is possible.

The hacking unencoding is to interprete every char as byte. For that use a single byte encoding. There is the standard provided charset ISO-8859-1.

```
    byte[] arr2 = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    s = new String(arr2, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    System.out.println(s);
```

Now the output is readable

```
Ошибка валидации атрибутов документа
```

which ironically means "Error validating document attributes."